# KeyError: 0 when trying to calculate value ratio after .explode() (Dataframe Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, pandas-explode

I'm studying data mining and my homework requires me to calculate the ratio of values in the dataset.
This homework is in .ipynb and there are process i must follow.

Here are the requirements in order:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByUfE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s3oL.png)
The dataset is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfo2D.png)
Here is my code for the 1st requirement

```
def str2dict(s: str) -> List[Dict]:
    """Convert given string to dict
    return list(eval(s))

for i in range (0,shape[0]):
    cate_col_df["payloads"][i] = str2dict(cate_col_df["payloads"][i])
cate_col_df = cate_col_df.explode("payloads")
```

Here is my code for the 2nd requirement

```
import copy
def missing_ratio(s):
    # TODO:
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    tmp = s.isna().sum()
    return (tmp / s.shape[0]).round(3)*100
    raise NotImplementedError()

def num_values(s):
    # TODO:
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    tmp = copy.deepcopy(s)
    if isinstance(s[0], dict):
        for i in range (0,shape[0]):
            tmp[i] = str(tmp[i])
    return len(tmp.dropna().unique())
    raise NotImplementedError()

def value_ratios(s):
    # TODO:
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    tmp = copy.deepcopy(s)
    if isinstance(s[0], dict):
        for i in range (0,shape[0]):
            tmp[i] = str(tmp[i])
    tmp1 = tmp.value_counts().to_dict()
    u = tmp.dropna().unique()
    for i in u:
       tmp1[i] = round(tmp1[i]/shape[0],3)*100
            
    return tmp1
    raise NotImplementedError()

cat_col_info_df = cate_col_df.agg([missing_ratio, num_values, value_ratios])
cat_col_info_df
```

My code run fine when i didn't run the code for 1st requirement, (but it is a wrong answer), however, if i run both of them, the error will be 'KeyError: 0'
I try to print the s variable and i can access s[0] but i don't know why it still annouce the error

The link to my dataset: https://github.com/MageOfFlowers/data/blob/master/rawdata-confidential/spaceX_laucnh.csv
Please ask me if you need more information